# Any Web service that helps you decide which mileage program to put your next mileage on?

Tags: online-resources, loyalty-programs

Is there any Web application that shows you a list of mileage programs that you can gain mileage on, given that you get on an flight X?

For example, if you get on a economy class with type S class from NRT to PEK in China Eastern Airlines, you can gain mileage on these programs (numbers and types are just illustration purposes only):

- Delta: 2310
- Alitalia: 1298
- Vietnam: 1298
- Korean Air: 2180
- Air France: 980

And it would be better if the service shows you not only the same alliance but a set of affiliated airlines.

Is there any such web service that enables you to compare and decide which mileage program to put your next flight mileage on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is. [wheretocredit](http://www.wheretocredit.com/) shows how many miles you could earn on any airline given an airline and booking class. It also has an [API](http://www.wheretocredit.com/api) if you're planning on writing some tool to query it.

Comment: Oh it's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: How about codeshare flights?

Comment: @MichaelTsang Codeshare flights earn according to the marketing airline. So if you fly a BA flight coded as AAnnn you'll earn according to the AA rates.